# how to schedule a reload of a qlikview application after successful completion of ETL process which runs on Informatica in UNIX environment

Tags: unix, informatica, qlikview

We have Qlikview application ready. we are moving application to production environment.

Now we need to schedule a reload of this application after successful completion of ETL process which is runs on informatica in unix environment.

Any suggestions or ideas how to do that, please.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at EDX triggers? Maybe there is a way to trigger QMC to start the job after informatica ETL with a script.